# Can SQL Server (2012-2014) be configured to run "on-demand?"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014, memory

I am very, very new to SQL, and am having difficulty configuring the server appropriately. All I have to work with for now is a small copy of the database schema of the company I work for, with randomized data in it. Running a small server with just a few tables that I only occasionally query to test applications, can I configure SQL to use resources "on-demand" (perhaps an agent that listens for queries, and does only this, not caching data in memory) or to use minimal system resources?

I find that, even with only 15 tables totaling 250MB in storage, SQL is always using at least 2GB of memory on a machine with only 8GB to spare.

I *did* look for similar questions here on StackExchange, but only found debates about how much memory to devote to the OS as opposed to the database on a server machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could disable SQL Server in the configuration manager when you are not using it and enable it when needed.  I do this on development machines when I am not specifically doing SQL work, keep a shortcut to SQL Server 2014 Configuration Manager handy.

In the installation process, I generally leave the Engine on Automatic during installation and set it to manual after the fact.  It is likely at the time I am installing it that I will be using it shortly and would like to verify it is working, or installing other items and may have to reboot, wanting the DB to come up right away.  Just my preference though.

Answer (score 6):

The best fit for your requirements is probably [SQL Server Express LocalDB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510202.aspx) (2012 and later).

It has a very small footprint, does not create a service, starts on demand, aggressively releases resources, and automatically shuts down a few minutes after the last connection to it is closed. LocalDB is specifically targeted to developers testing on a local machine. Things like external connectivity and SQL Agent are not available.

More information:

[Introducing LocalDB, an improved SQL Express](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlexpress/2011/07/12/introducing-localdb-an-improved-sql-express/)
[SQL Express v LocalDB v SQL Compact Edition](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jerrynixon/archive/2012/02/26/sql-express-v-localdb-v-sql-compact-edition.aspx)
[Getting Started with SQL Server 2012 Express LocalDB](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2694/getting-started-with-sql-server-2012-express-localdb/)